# C# How to make seperate Panels move in different directions with a timer

Tags: c#

Ok, so I am working on a game engine, and I want to be able to make different Panels (the objects for the game engine) move when I check a checkbox

But, I just don't know how to do so.

```
    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Panel> kvp in objects)
        {
            if (running)
            {
                Point loc = kvp.Value.Location;
                loc.X = loc.X + 1;
                kvp.Value.Location = loc;
            }
        }
    }
```

So for this code makes all objects move to the left, but say I want only one object to move and the other ones stay still, how would I do that?

I have a text box that you type in to find the object but you have to click a button to find it.

This is just a really confusing part of the Engine and I promised my self I wouldn't give up on it.

Comment: Which of these objects do you want to move versus the ones that stay the same. Your code currently looks like you loop through all the objects and apply the movement. So `objects.First()` would make it so that you only move the first one, but not the rest.

Comment: Well there is a textbox where you choose an object, but I don't know how to tell the timer to move that one object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
First give your object reasonable names that the user can see as the panel name from your UI, then identify them based on those names.
So panel1 should have text propery as "panel1".

This code should work though I have not tried it.

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Panel> kvp in objects)
    {
        if (running && textbox1.Text.Trim() == kvp.Name.Trim()) // you could also do null check if you like
        {
            Point loc = kvp.Value.Location;
            loc.X = loc.X + 1;
            kvp.Value.Location = loc;
        }
    }
}
```

I dont understand what you mean by different directions,  if you want them to move in different random direction then you would generate random numbers between 1 and 2 then if the number is 1 you do loc.X +1 but if its 2  loc.X -1.   If you want the user to select the direction then you can create a Combo box for that.

Comment: I will try this out.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: It worked very similar, but I will start playing around with it.
Thank You